# looking for a sf book on time travel

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I have been looking for a SF book about an old man (tailor) walking down the street. He steps through a wormhole and ends up in the future. His adventures start from there. I read the story back in 1970-1980, and it was from an old paperback I got from the library. 
What I remember was an old tailor closing up shop to head home one evening, and as he was walking down the street he stumbled on a crack in the sidewalk and was transported into the future. That's about all I can remember right now. I have Googled it online but, with so few facts I cannot seem to find anything. I know it was an old book from about the same time as E.E. "Doc" Smith stories of the Lensmans.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[That would be "Pebble in the Sky" by Isaac Asimov.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebble_in_the_Sky)

The tailor is zapped far into the future through a nuclear accident, to a time when mankind has reached the stars.  Earth is a radioactive mess and shunned by the galactic empire.

Among other adventures, Joseph Schwartz is given a treatment intended to help learn the new language better.  It also changes his brain structure and allows him to read and control other people's minds.

---

It has been a long time since I read this one.  I need to buy a copy and reread it.  It is a good story.

"Grow old along with me, the best is yet to be."